# Publishing to Glassfish 4 at localhost [domain1] has encountered

Tags: java, glassfish

I am getting the following errors when I try to run a web app in eclipse using glassfish server.

I have 3 folder namely; Testdb, TestdbEJB and TestdbWeb. Can someone help me to resolve this issue please?

> cannot Deploy Testdb deploy is failing=Error occurred during
>   deployment: Application Testdb is trying to use the same repository
>   directory as application TestDb, please choose a different application
>   name to deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you deployed an application named **TestDb** before and now you are trying to deploy an application named **Testdb**, but you didn't properly undeploy the first one.

It isn't possible to deploy two applications with the same name (it doesn't matter that the case is not matching) at the same time...the reason is obvious.

**How to fix it:**

1. Try to log in to Glassfish Admin UI (http://localhost:4848), go to Applications und undeploy the first application. You may also use **asadmin** instead. Try to redeploy your application then.
2. If nothing is listed under "Applications", check the folder `glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/` of your Glassfish installation, if there is a folder named "TestDb" (or anything like this), delete it, you may also check the "__internal" folder. Restart Glassfish afterwards.
3. If you deleted something in step 2 and it still doesn't work, open `/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml` of your Glassfish installation and search for the section beginning with `<application>` which represents your application. Delete the part from (inclusive) `<application>` to `</application>`, save the file and restart Glassfish.

Comment: Is that conflicting with another port or something like that? 

I'm unbale to delete the folder TestDb as it says it contains the mysql driver jar file which is open in Java Platform binary. Please help ! 
Since the morning I am struggling with this :/

Comment: Looks like you have to stop the server to delete the folder.

Comment: Right bro.. I stopped it Task Manager.. 
I have done Step 2.. What should I do next ?

Comment: Start the server and deploy your application.

Comment: I did and its giving the following error:

HTTP 404 - Not Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.

Comment: This is a different problem...please mark this question as solved and create a new one.

Comment: Hey it is now working.. 
But I have included the mysql jar file into the TestdbEJB folder through build path but its giving me java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Please help :( 
I'm gonna mark this question as SOLVED !

Comment: You can't package a JAR into an EJB because that is also a JAR. The easy solution is to put the driver into the `/glassfish/lib/` folder.

Comment: You are a life saviour man.. I'm sorry I am unable to vote your answer up since I am new here.. But I've marked it as accepted.. :) 
Thanks a lot.. 

So it means whenever I have to include an API (jar file), I have to put into the `/glassfish/lib/1` folder manually ?

Comment: You are welcome. The alternative is to create an EAR which contains your EJB, the WAR and the libs (jar files). If you don't really need the separation into EJB and WAR, you can also include your services from the EJB in the WAR (just move all classes to the WAR) and add the lib as dependency of the WAR (then it will get packaged into the WAR's lib folder). Google can help you to find a tutorial how to do these kind of things :)

Comment: Hmm.. This seems interesting too.. 

Do you have any well-explained link to demonstrate this hierarchy EAR ?
would be of great help since I am actually working on JSP & EJB with JDBC..